# Bind a file inside a maven built EAR

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

Below is my project structure.
[image]

I require to copy a file from the location \MainProject\src\non-packaged-resources to the \MainProject\sub-project2\sub-project2-web\src\main\resources location on building the MainProject. 
Below is the build section of the pom file of my sub-project2-web but the file is not copied while building.

```
    <build>
    <finalName>sub-project2-web</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceExcludes>**/.copyarea.db</warSourceExcludes>
                <packagingExcludes>**/.copyarea.db</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <!-- here the phase you need -->
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>/src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>/src/non-packaged-resources</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When observing the build log, it skips the file being copied with the below error

```
skip non existing resourceDirectory
```

But the maven build gets successful. 
Goal is to bind the file which exists inside the \MainProject\src\non-packaged-resources to all the ears (sub-project1.ear, sub-project2.ear) on building the maven project. First I am trying to test this in the sub-project2-web only. 
Please advice on how to provide correct paths based on this requirement. 
I am using maven 2.2.1 version (project is built on this.)

Answer (score 1):

Define the paths with reference to your project base directory as follows.

```
<outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/sub-project2/sub-project2-web/src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
```

---

```
<directory>${project.basedir}/src/non-packaged-resources</directory>
```

Then add it in the `pom.xml` file in the `maven-resources-plugin`.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <!-- here the phase you need -->
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/sub-project2/sub-project2-web/src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/non-packaged-resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the heads up. I got an idea based on your answer how to track the parent directories. My answer is as below.

Comment: Great, waiting to see your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above answer I found the correct way to get the locations of the parent and the base directories. Below worked for me.

```
<build>
<finalName>sub-project2-web</finalName>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <warSourceExcludes>**/.copyarea.db</warSourceExcludes>
            <packagingExcludes>**/.copyarea.db</packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-resources</id>
                <!-- here the phase you need -->
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>                         
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>                      
                            <directory>${project.parent.parent.basedir}/src/non-packaged-resources</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```